# Node authentication in ns2 simulator with passing password

Tags: cygwin

I have tried to do node creation in ns2. now i want to authenticate nodes in that one node behaves as a server and authenticate nodes with passing password between them. I have tried but i don't know more about how to do c++ programming with ns2. I am using cygwin for ns2.

Answer (score -1):

You can use existing protocols in ns2 as a base of your work. For example VANETRBC protocol written by Daniel Jungels in vehicular ad-hoc networks give you a general view for designing new communication protocols. Or project report in the following document can help your for starting your project: http://sce.uhcl.edu/transa/Sourcecode/NS-2_Security_Node_Document.doc